# Client/Server; Server throws EOFException after Client code complete

Tags: java, sockets, client

I am trying to set up a simple Client/Server model where is send an object via a `DataInput/OutputStream`. My Client code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String HOST_NAME = "localhost"; 
    final int PORT_NUMBER = 9090;

    Card card = new Card(0, 0, 0, 0);

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER);
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        output.writeObject(card);
        card = new Card(1, 1, 1, 1);
        output.writeObject(card);
        output.writeObject(null);

        output.close();
        input.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Can not recognize: " + HOST_NAME);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Bad port number: " + PORT_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

On the Server side, I have tried several variations of code, the current one looks like this:

```
static boolean listening = true;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
    while (listening) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        try {
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            while ((card = (Card) input.readObject()) != null) {
                for (int feature : card.getFeatures()) {
                    System.out.println(feature + " ");
                }
            }

            output.close();
            input.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simplified and working version of what I want. I want the server to keep listening for new Card objects and printing their features until it gets a null object. However, what happens when I run this is that the features of the first card are printed then I immediately get an EOFException on the server end.

I've tried different variations of the above, including using a `finally` to break out of the `while`, but in every case I never make it past printing the first card. How can I guarantee that the server will keep listening and receiving cards until the Client closes the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ((card = (Card) input.readObject()) != null) {
```

Unless you're planning on sending yourself a `null` to terminate this loop, this isn't a valid way to read an `ObjectInputStream.` The `readObject()` method doesn't return `null` at end of stream: it throws `EOFException.` So, you have to catch it. So the loop condition should really be `while (true),` and the `readObject()` call needs to be inside the loop. Then you either have to have

```
try
{
    card = (Card)input.readObject();
    // ...
}
catch (EOFException)
{
    break;
}
```

inside the loop, or have the loop *inside* a try/catch block with a `catch (EOFException)` which now doesn't need a `break;`.

Comment: I like this solution, I got it to work as you mentioned by feeding a `null` to the Server, but that seems like a work around.

Comment: It's not only a workaround, it prevents you from sending a null for any other reason.